# How do I change the icon size and padding in the Gnome 3 upper panel on Linux Mint 12?

Tags: linux-mint, gnome3

I'm trying to personalize the desktop interface in Linux Mint 12 running Gnome 3. I just disabled the bottom panel and I changed the font in the upper panel. How do I change the upper panel's icon size and padding?

Modifying the `PANEL_ICON_SIZE` setting in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js` causes the system to freeze and the upper panel disappears.

Comment: You might want to look into editing `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css`. Something like [this reference](http://joneslee85.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/howto-customize-gnome-shell-theme/) might be helpful.